# npm run build results in an error when I run it in a Dockerised environment

Tags: javascript, docker, next.js, environment-variables

I am trying to host my website through a Docker container but i am facing an issue during the build process.

Following is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:18-alpine AS base

FROM base AS deps
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm ci

FROM base AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .

RUN sed -E -n 's/[^#]+/export &/ p' .env.production.local >> .envvars
RUN source .envvars && npm run build

FROM base AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production

RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs

COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public

RUN mkdir .next
RUN chown nextjs:nodejs .next

COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static

USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3001

ENV PORT 3001
ENV HOSTNAME "0.0.0.0"

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

When the build process reaches a line in my code that parses the Firebase Service Key, I get the following error: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token t in JSON at position 1`. This error does not however occur if I build the website outside the docker env (my local machine).

Following is the parsing code:

```js
const serviceAccountKey = process.env.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY;

      if (!serviceAccountKey) {
        throw new Error('FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY is missing');
      }

      let saK;

      if (typeof serviceAccountKey === 'string') {
        try {
          saK = JSON.parse(serviceAccountKey);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY is not a valid JSON', error.stack);
        }
      } else if (typeof serviceAccountKey === 'object') {
        saK = serviceAccountKey;
      }
```

Why does it fail when my Docker image is building?